# What is the reason that my code is badly formatted?

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I would be grateful if someone tell me what I did wrong when posting my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056507/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-inside-stored-procedure/15134887#15134887).

As you may notice the code is not formatted.

**Edited:**

@meta.michael said that there are no line breaks in my code, but look at this screenshot from Notepad++:

[image]

so shouldn't the line breaks be copied and pasted to the stacoverflow's window?

Thanks for the help. I've tried to format this code properly for a half an our and I've read the help but I could not make it right.

Comment: Please have a look at [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). You have not used four spaces to format it as a code and also there is not any line-break in your code.

Comment: It doesn't appear to have any linebreaks in it. After that you'll need to indent each line 4 spaces. Highlight and Ctl-k or click the editor's `{}` button.

Comment: I made an attempt at cleaning it up. You mixed plenty of tabs into there as well. Please review.

Comment: And always view preview while editing code. :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. So how should I copy and paste my code safely to the window? I've copied the code that is in the screenshot. @hims056 I was doing that but I could not make it right so I've decided to post it anyway and get help here:)

Answer (score 1):

It's all said in the yellow stripe just above the form. Tab Code. So read it:

---

To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces:

```
    This will be displayed in a monospaced font. The first four spaces
    will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved.

    Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
    <i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a link](http://example.com)
```

To create not a block, but an inline code span, use backticks:

The `$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
If you want to have a preformatted block within a list, indent by eight spaces:

```
1. This is normal text.
2. So is this, but now follows a code block:

        Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
        That's four spaces for the list
        and four to trigger the code block.
```

Comment: Thanks for birnging that up.